# Neo4j 3.0 Mazerunner compatibility

Tags: neo4j, nosql

Does anybody know if Neo4j 3.0 is compatible with Mazerunner? Has anybody tried to connect Mazerunner to their Neo4j 3.0 database?

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mazerunner

Comment: could you link to Mazerunner? or be a little more specific? google returns the movie :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it has not been updated for Neo4j 3.0. It currently targets Neo4j 2.2.1 I believe.

For using Neo4j 3.x with Spark I would suggest using [neo4j-spark-connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector). It takes advantage of the new Bolt binary protocol in Neo4j 3.0 and the official Java driver to work with Spark and Neo4j.